# Authorize.net Magento 2 EE patch

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, authorize.net

I saw this link: https://github.com/MeetanshiInc/Magento-Authorize-Net-Direct-Post-Patch-for-M1-M2

Just wondering, does the patch for CE 2.1.0 - 2.1.9 work for EE 2.1.5 as well? Just curious.

Comment: It's only for community edition not for EE

Comment: It will not work, you have to download from magneto account. there are different patches available for different version.

Answer (score 0):

For Magento Commerce 2.X and Magento Open Source 2.X, follow these steps to download and install the patch:

1. Access My Account.
2. Navigate to Downloads tab. Select the Magento edition and version
   (like Magento Commerce 2.X), then edition and version (like Commerce
   2.X).There are two patches available. One patch can be used to update Magento 2.0.X and  2.1.X, the other one can be used to update
   Magento 2.2.X and 2.3.X.
3. Select Support Patches, then Authorize.net Direct Post Signature Key
   patch.
4. Download and install the Authorize.net Direct Post Signature Key
   patch for your Magento version.

**There are two support patches available for EE for Authorize.net**

- 2.2.x-2.3.0 - Authorize.net Signature Key patch - EE
- 2.0.x-2.1.x - Authorize.net Signature Key patch - EE

To be more specific, following is the screenshot of my account for Magento EE 2.2.5.

[image]

**I hope this will help and this will answer your query**

Comment: @Didi If my answer is helpful then please mark my answer correct so it's helps others as well. keep coding :) thanks :)